# Difference between event group id and event ids in someip sd

Tags: events, ethernet, automotive

I have a small query regarding someip sd, in `vsomeip` stack `eventgroups` for the server are configured as follows

```
            {
                "eventgroup" : "0x4465",
                "events" : [ "0x778", "0x779" ],
                "is_multicast" : "true"                                        
            }
```

server offers a service for the eventgroup 0x4465,
when client subscribes to the event group id 0x4465 ,  client gets the notifications with event id as 0x0778 in someip header, is it correct? or client should get the notifications with event id as 0x4465(same as eventgroup id) in someip header.which is correct way

Answer (score 2):

Event Groups are just logical grouping of events, they only exist at the service discovery level `SOME/IP-SD`.

The events themselves contain no information about the event groups, and will use the ids `0x778` and `0x779`.