# Where does the Eventgroup ID in SOME/IP Service Discovery come from

Tags: autosar, automotive, vsomeip

How and where(actually 'who' is making the eventgroups) are the events assigned to eventgroups. I looked in the SOME/IP SD specification and it seems that they are just there.

The client gets the offerService message from an ECU, containing service ID, instance ID, major and minor version. Then the client 'answers' sends a SubscribeEventgroup message containig the Eventgroup ID. For me the Eventgroup ID magically appears. Where am I getting it wrong?

Thanks in advance.

This is more or less a follow up question to [Difference between event group id and event ids in someip sd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64119924/difference-between-event-group-id-and-event-ids-in-someip-sd)

Searched the official SOME/IP SD specification (and SOME/IP specification) and googled alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service discovery can create quite a load on the network. Event groups have been defined to keep the network utilisation in check. Instead of having to subscribe to each event individually, it is possible to subscribe to a group of events in one go.

Event groups are typically part of the system design, which means that event groups are typically defined in an OEM role.